# In Flutter how to obtain the initialSelection value

Tags: flutter

How the default value set in dropdown to appear in the output string when I click the button. The default value is seen in the dropdown but selectedColor is null. I have to click on the default value in the dropdown menue in order for selectedColor to have value.

Is there a better way to update selectedColour something like `DropdownMenu.getInitialSelectionValue()`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const DropdownMenuExample());
}

// DropdownMenuEntry labels and values for the first dropdown menu.
enum ColorLabel {
  blue('Blue', Colors.blue),
  pink('Pink', Colors.pink),
  green('Green', Colors.green),
  yellow('Orange', Colors.orange),
  grey('Grey', Colors.grey);

  const ColorLabel(this.label, this.color);
  final String label;
  final Color color;
}

// DropdownMenuEntry labels and values for the second dropdown menu.
enum IconLabel {
  smile('Smile', Icons.sentiment_satisfied_outlined),
  cloud(
    'Cloud',
    Icons.cloud_outlined,
  ),
  brush('Brush', Icons.brush_outlined),
  heart('Heart', Icons.favorite);

  const IconLabel(this.label, this.icon);
  final String label;
  final IconData icon;
}

class DropdownMenuExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropdownMenuExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<DropdownMenuExample> createState() => _DropdownMenuExampleState();
}

class _DropdownMenuExampleState extends State<DropdownMenuExample> {
  final TextEditingController colorController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController iconController = TextEditingController();
  ColorLabel? selectedColor;
  IconLabel? selectedIcon;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        colorSchemeSeed: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    DropdownMenu<ColorLabel>(
                      initialSelection: ColorLabel.green,
                      controller: colorController,
                      requestFocusOnTap: true,
                      label: const Text('Color'),
                      onSelected: (ColorLabel? color) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedColor = color;
                        });
                      },
                      dropdownMenuEntries: ColorLabel.values
                          .map<DropdownMenuEntry<ColorLabel>>(
                              (ColorLabel color) {
                        return DropdownMenuEntry<ColorLabel>(
                          value: color,
                          label: color.label,
                          enabled: color.label != 'Grey',
                          style: MenuItemButton.styleFrom(
                            foregroundColor: color.color,
                          ),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                        'You selected a ${selectedColor?.label}'),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                      child: Icon(
                        selectedIcon?.icon,
                        color: selectedColor?.color,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I just edited my post to give you Option B, which is closer to what you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option A:**
You declared the `selectedColor` variable in the top of that class:

```
class _DropdownMenuExampleState extends State<DropdownMenuExample> {
[...]
ColorLabel? selectedColor; // here
```

You need to give it a value, as it's null right now, as you said. You could just assign it right there as initialization using the ColorLabel constructor you defined:

```
ColorLabel? selectedColor = ColorLabel('Blue', Colors.blue);
```

Normally, you would save the selection (when changed) to "shared prefs" or something and restore that when restarting the app, so the "last user selection" is pre-selected instead of 'blue'.

**Option B:** (matches your question better)

you actually GET the value from the dropdown AFTER creating it.
in short:

```
DropdownMenu menu = DropdownMenu < ColorLabel > ( ...
[...]
selectedColor = menu.initialSelection;
```

Therefore, I created a `getDropdownMenu` function, that just contains your dropdown-code but reads the initial selection value and then returns it. It's tricky to do that directly in the `build` function, sometimes you can use `.then(){` to do stuff like this... Anyway, it's pretty simple, you define the dropdown and read `initialSelection` and assign it to your `selectedColor` variable, in a separate function. Full code here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
    runApp(const DropdownMenuExample());
}

// DropdownMenuEntry labels and values for the first dropdown menu.
enum ColorLabel {
    blue('Blue', Colors.blue),
        pink('Pink', Colors.pink),
        green('Green', Colors.green),
        yellow('Orange', Colors.orange),
        grey('Grey', Colors.grey);

    const ColorLabel(this.label, this.color);
    final String label;
    final Color color;
}

// DropdownMenuEntry labels and values for the second dropdown menu.
enum IconLabel {
    smile('Smile', Icons.sentiment_satisfied_outlined),
        cloud(
            'Cloud',
            Icons.cloud_outlined,
        ),
        brush('Brush', Icons.brush_outlined),
        heart('Heart', Icons.favorite);

    const IconLabel(this.label, this.icon);
    final String label;
    final IconData icon;
}

class DropdownMenuExample extends StatefulWidget {
    const DropdownMenuExample({
        super.key
    });

    @override
    State < DropdownMenuExample > createState() => _DropdownMenuExampleState();
}

class _DropdownMenuExampleState extends State < DropdownMenuExample > {
    final TextEditingController colorController = TextEditingController();
    final TextEditingController iconController = TextEditingController();
    ColorLabel ? selectedColor;
    IconLabel ? selectedIcon;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            theme: ThemeData(
                useMaterial3: true,
                colorSchemeSeed: Colors.green,
            ),
            home: Scaffold(
                body: SafeArea(
                    child: Column(
                        children: < Widget > [
                            Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                                    child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: < Widget > [
                                            getDropdownMenu(),
                                        ],
                                    ),
                            ),
                            Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: < Widget > [
                                    Text(
                                        'You selected a ${selectedColor?.label}'),
                                    Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                                            child: Icon(
                                                selectedIcon?.icon,
                                                color: selectedColor?.color,
                                            ),
                                    )
                                ],
                            )
                        ],
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    DropdownMenu getDropdownMenu() {
        DropdownMenu menu = DropdownMenu < ColorLabel > (
            initialSelection: ColorLabel.green,
            controller: colorController,
            requestFocusOnTap: true,
            label: const Text('Color'),
                onSelected: (ColorLabel ? color) {
                    setState(() {
                        selectedColor = color;
                    });
                },
                dropdownMenuEntries: ColorLabel.values
                .map < DropdownMenuEntry < ColorLabel >> (
                    (ColorLabel color) {
                        return DropdownMenuEntry < ColorLabel > (
                            value: color,
                            label: color.label,
                            enabled: color.label != 'Grey',
                            style: MenuItemButton.styleFrom(
                                foregroundColor: color.color,
                            ),
                        );
                    }).toList(),
        );
        selectedColor = menu.initialSelection;
        return menu;
    }
}
```